# How to disable GPUImageGrayscaleFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gpuimage

I have attached `GPUImageGrayscaleFilter` in a chain with some other filters like so:

```
[self.image addTarget:self.sepiaFilter];
[self.sepiaFilter addTarget:self.brightnessFilter];
[self.brightnessFilter addTarget:self.grayscaleFilter];
[self.grayscaleFilter addTarget:self.imageView];
[self.image processImage];
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to do something like:

```
grayscaleFilter.shutoff = YES;
```

I'd like for my users to be able to turn on grayscale or turn it off. I'm wondering if I can accomplish this without having to remove it from the chain?

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish what I want to above, have to remove `GPUImageGrayscaleFilter` from the filter chain in order to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to chain the filters:

```
- (void) chainFilters
{
    [self.gpuImage removeAllTargets];

    Filter *previousFilter = nil, *firstFilter = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.filters count]; i++)
    {
        Filter *currentFilter = [[self.filters objectAtIndex:i] retain];
        [currentFilter.filter removeAllTargets];

        if ([currentFilter applied])
        {
            if (!firstFilter)
            {
                firstFilter = [currentFilter retain];
            }

            if (previousFilter)
            {
                [previousFilter.filter addTarget:currentFilter.filter];
                [previousFilter release];
            }

            previousFilter = [currentFilter retain];
        }

        [currentFilter release];
    }

    if (firstFilter != nil)
    {
        [self.gpuImage addTarget:firstFilter.filter];
        [previousFilter.filter addTarget:self.gpuImageView];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.gpuImage addTarget:self.gpuImageView];
    }

    [previousFilter release];
    [firstFilter release];
}
```

Where Filter is a wrapper class for GPUImageFilter. I apply this each time a filter changes. Don't know if it's the most efficient but it gets the job done. I think there are some other classes within GPUImage like FilterGroup and FilterPipeline that make this easier though I haven't messed with them yet.